# Hinting/Censoring function lua

Tags: string, lua

Is it possible to make a hinting/censor function with Lua which basically replaces most of the characters with asterisks. Example:

```
censor("Answer")
```

Output :

```
"A****r"
```

I've tried many things, but I couldn't succeed. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Check out Regular Expressions.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following function which makes use of [`string.gsub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub):

```
function censor(word)
    return string.gsub(word, "^(.)(.*)(.)$", function(a, b, c)
        return a .. string.rep("*", #b) .. c
    end)
end
```

You may want to read about [patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1), which will help you craft string substitution and string matching expressions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function censor(word)
   return word:sub(1,1)..string.rep("*",#word-2)..word:sub(-1,-1)
end
```

Comment: One minor issue: if you pass a string that is a single character, the resulting string is that character duplicated.